# Python Selenium - Skip user if private (Instagram)

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I'm relatively new to python and selenium, so I hope my question is not that stupid.
My intention is to get the locations of each post by certain users with the help of Selenium. That I was already able to finish.

Now my problem is:
When one of my selected users has a private account, it returns an error message and stops my loop. Unfortunately there is now attribute with the message that the user is a private user if she/he is public. So I can not say: Skip this user if this class/id etc. displays that specific message. Do you have an idea how to handle this problem?

Best,

Mow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFoSm.png)

Comment: have your tried to put a try and except block, such that even if the code throws and error, your loop wouldn't break